# Node.js is stuck after "npm run dev"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I installed the latest react and next.js versions.
after building a new project with npx create-next-app,
the first thing that I do inside the vs code is "npm run dev"
and I get the warning: warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload

Now I didn't write a single line of code and the terminal is stuck.
I tried re-installing react,next.js, I tried to re-build the package and I do not understand what is the problem.

Will be helpful if you guys can help.
Thanks.

edit:

the full console output after me running npm run dev:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

event - compiled client and server successfully in 498 ms (166 modules)

wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...

event - compiled client and server successfully in 85 ms (167 modules)

warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload

wait  - compiling / (client and server)...

event - compiled client and server successfully in 140 ms (170 modules)

warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
```

And then it stucks so I do ctrl+c to terminate the process.

I am using react version: 18.2.0
and next.js version: 13.1.1

Comment: What command line program are you using to issue to command?

Comment: Please show the console output. Also, what is your node version?

Comment: So `localhost:3000` doesn't work now? Or changes in code don't recompile?

Comment: @Konrad its working but my terminal is stuck.

Comment: @Gilbert just started a new project so I ran "npm run dev" in the terminal, first thing that I did

Comment: React is currently in version 18, are you sure that you are using 8?

Comment: @Konrad My bad, I am using version 18.

Comment: show me your package.json file

Comment: @NaveenRavi
{
  "name": "test",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}

Comment: What do you mean when you say the terminal is stuck? The behavior as you describe it otherwise sounds quite normal. The "fast refresh" is just a warning, as it says, not a fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

Open link http://localhost:3000/

Somehow it worked for me after opening this link `npm run dev` terminal process resumed.